# How can I prevent the present working directory to sync between tabs in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

I think this behavior is annoying because I want to use tabs specifically to be able to work on two directories simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant commands are documented at `:h current-directory`. Basically, you should use `:lcd` and/or `:tcd` instead of `:cd`.